# How do I select for a -webkit-scrollbar-button once the track has reached the limit in that direction?

Tags: css, css-selectors, webkit, scrollbar, styling

I want to set the css of scrollbar buttons once the scrollbar thumb has reached the end in that direction. That is, I want to select the :decrement button when the scroll thumb cannot be decremented any more. The default scroll bar grays out buttons when they're in contact with the thumb. I thought the :disabled selector would do what I want, but no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}
/* Buttons */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 13px;
  width: 16px;
}
/* Up */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555555 transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent #777777 transparent;
}
/* Down */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
  border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  border-color: #555555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:single-button:increment:hover {
  border-color: #777777 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```